# Jquery.form AjaxSubmit adding tags to response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

When I ajaxSubmit a form, the service returns a number. For some reason, ajaxSubmit seems to add a bunch of tags to it.

```
        form.ajaxSubmit(function(data){
          alert(data);
    });
});
```

Here, the alert prints out: `"<head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">130</pre></body>"`

Whereas if I check in my debugger, the value is simply 130.

[image]
[image]

I have made the assumption that since the service seems to return a correct value, this issue is caused only on the clientside. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

**Why is the value different in the javascript from that in the response?**

Comment: what is the form submitting? some WYSIWYG textarea?

Comment: A fileinput and a hidden id-field. (And as far as I know, the fileinput works kind of quirky with ajaxsubmit so it transforms it into a textarea. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) )

Comment: That window is HTML, so technically the mark is still there

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory: Could you elaborate a little? Why is the 'window' HTML, if I'm only returning a long?

Comment: For example, if you right click on the 130 and inspect that element; you should see your mark up. It's a little Inception-like,  but open the dev tools in the dev tools.

Comment: It's a regular alert, not an element I can inspect. It looks exactly like below: 

The page at localhost:8080 says: <head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">134</pre></body>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that jquery.form doesn't expect to receive plaintext, it expects either JSON, XML, HTML or Script.

So I solved this by sending JSON-data from the serverside, and specifying that JSON was the expected format at the clientside.

```
form.ajaxSubmit(
        {dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data) });
```

Comment: Thanks @Soroush, this saved me a bunch of time! I lost another 20 minutes though when I forgot to put double-quotes around my json variable names in my response.  If anyone else makes this same mistake just know that the form plug-in won't call your success or your fail method.  You can use the ajaxError event to trap this (I should have!).

Comment: From the [docs](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object):
"One of: null, 'xml', 'script', or 'json'". Although HTML is supported in the $.ajax standard object, it looks like HTML isn't supported...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using [this jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). Its [API](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api) states:

> Note: You can pass any of the standard $.ajax options to ajaxForm

Have you tried passing it the `dataType` option? Like this:

```
form.ajaxSubmit({
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data){ alert(data); }
});
```

Comment: I tried to pass the dataType parameter, but with the same result unfortunatly.

Comment: As I noted in a previous comment above, the docs don't mention HTML as a valid option for `dataType`. Maybe it isn't supported...